# My father rejected proposal

Tags: nikah

Asalamu alaikum my muslim brothers and sisters. I associate with a guy that i want to be with for the sake of Allah. This guy made a proposal to marry me to my father but my father rejected it. The guy that wanted to marry me was a good guy wether it be personality or deen wise. My father said no because or tribal and cultural reasoning. my father stated that his people don't marry that kind of people. So my father basically doesn't care about the guy, nothing against him... he just doesn't like his family because of his own personal reasoning. I don't know what to do in this case but i don't see myself with anyone else but him. I attempted to talk to him and change his mind but he still refused. Also other elders that i got to talk to about the situation to my father..... still no. I'm positive he will forever be settled down at NO.

Comment: You shouldn't have deleted your former post as it was simply the same as this one. Each post has an edit link so you can change/edit your post to make it fit our policies. And as it seems you were pointed at this option. Duplicates of the same question are rather disliked.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The best way is to convince your father but don’t forget he’ll never listen to you , he raised you when you was child and still thinks that you are a child.
So speak with your uncle or one his friends to talk to him and convince him.

Comment: Iv'e tried that aswell. No matter who tells him what about the situation he is forever against it.

Comment: Iv'e tried that aswell. No matter who tells him what about the situation he is forever against it.

Comment: Welcome to Islam SE. Answers should be elaborate and focused on addressing the question. Claims should be supported by evidence. Please visit our [tour] in the [help], and refer to [answer].